# Unity 2020.1.1f1 No multiplayer in Services

Tags: unity-game-engine, service, multiplayer

I'm trying to set up unity for Cloud Anchors application. To do that I have to set up multiplayer. In unity 2020.1.1f1 documentation there is a tab called Multiplayer in Services. Unfortunately it doesn't appear in Unity editor. Does anyone know what could be the reason? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `To start using Unity Multiplayer, your project must be set up to use Unity Services.` .. is this the case for your project?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, but my problem was solved an hour ago, all you have to do is click on the dashboard in services and go to the multiplayer page (you do not need the multiplayer button in services) I just played with my friend online